# Transfer content in listview to an sql database c#

Tags: c#, database, listview, connection

I'm trying to make a small program, which reads a txt file and reports everything in order as I decided in the listview, then I would like the contents of the listview (also composed of 500, 600 lines) to be transferred to a mysql database. This is the code I'm trying to use but it doesn't work for me, when I try to transfer the strings to the database I get this error, on the database the columns are set as nvchar (50), can you help me thanks (link the img for example)[image][image]

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string cd = "INSERT INTO dbo.example2(timID,timTipo,timDataTempo,timDataOra,timBadge,timTerId,timVerso,timFlag1,timFlag2,timCampo1,timCampo2,timCampo3,timCampo4,timCampo5,timCampo6,timCampo7,timCampo8,timCampo9,timCampo10,timTasto,upsize_ts,timDataInserimento,timAppScrivente,CodiceErrore) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,@d17,@d18,@d19,@d20,@d21,@d22,@d23,@d24)";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Timbrautre;UID=prova;PWD=OfficeLine21");
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(cd) { Connection = conn };



            foreach (ListViewItem l in listView1.Items)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", l.SubItems[0].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", l.SubItems[1].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", l.SubItems[2].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", l.SubItems[3].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", l.SubItems[4].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6", l.SubItems[5].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", l.SubItems[6].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d8", l.SubItems[7].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d9", l.SubItems[8].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d10", l.SubItems[9].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d11", l.SubItems[10].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d12", l.SubItems[11].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d13", l.SubItems[12].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d14", l.SubItems[13].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d15", l.SubItems[14].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d16", l.SubItems[15].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d17", l.SubItems[16].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d18", l.SubItems[17].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d19", l.SubItems[18].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d20", l.SubItems[19].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d21", l.SubItems[20].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d22", l.SubItems[21].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d23", l.SubItems[22].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d24", l.SubItems[23].Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?
Check types of your @d.. parameters - you add all of them as strings, however, some fields in database maybe numeric, so you need conversion.

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Declare the scalar variable "@ d1".'

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the dataTypes in the sql site
my recomendation would be to add the parameter like this

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateCheck", MySqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = ToCheckTime;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@orderid", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = item[1];
```

Not with .AddWithValue

and make sure the DBType is correct

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried to put the code as suggested but the above error persists

Comment: you mean the same? as you attached?

Comment: yes, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Declare the scalar variable "@ d1".'

Comment: there is a space between @ and "d" is it only a type error or you copied this from vs,
If copied just remove the space, Make sure the parameter name same as in the sql

Comment: Hi, I checked how you told me about this space between the @ and d but I can't find it all seems without space.

Comment: Hi there, did you solved your issue, if not could it be possbible that you send your source code and a take a look at, Just a qs. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Initial Catalog=Timbrautre;Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            _con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");

            int i = 0;
            foreach (ListViewItem l in listView1.Items)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO  dbo.example2 (timID,timTipo,timDataTempo,timDataOra,timBadge,timTerId,timVerso,timFlag1,timFlag2,timCampo1,timCampo2,timCampo3,timCampo4,timCampo5,timCampo6,timCampo7,timCampo8,timCampo9,timCampo10,timTasto,upsize_ts,timDataInserimento,timAppScrivente,CodiceErrore) values('" + l.SubItems[0].Text + "' " + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[1].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[2].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[3].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[4].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[5].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[6].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[7].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[8].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[9].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[10].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[11].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[12].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[13].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[14].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[15].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[16].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[17].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[18].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[19].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[20].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[21].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[22].Text + "'" + "," + " '" + l.SubItems[23].Text + "');", _con);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                i++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Scritto fino alla Timbratura:" + i.ToString());
            _con.Close();

        }
    }
```